# Move constructor with vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, move-constructor

How should i do the move constructor for a vector with pointers?
for example :
I have this in class A as a field - `vector<A*> AList;`
In the function `(A &&otherA)` ( which is the move constructor) ,
should i write like this :
`AList(std::move(other.AList))` or in an other way?

Comment: More data required. `std:vector` is [Rule of Five compliant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), so you shouldn't need to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it like that.

Or, if you don't need the move assignment operator to do anything else, just leave it out and the compiler will do this for you.

This goes for moving *any* member vector.